# Unexpected result when using .map to apply a function against array, seem to duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js, dictionary

I'm parsing data from a local file containing a list of user agents to an array.  Then I'm using map to apply a replace function to the strings held in the array, to escape them for regex parsing later.

However, the replace seems to be duplicating.  I get output like this:

```
  ['downloader touch pfs 1\\.3\\.1',
  'downloader pfs 1\\.3\\.1',
  'downloader touch pfs 1\\.2\\.6',
  'awi v5\\.12\\.843']
```

Here is the function:

```
function getUAs() {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var data = fs.readFileSync('./../resources/badUA.txt');
        var array = data.toString().split("\n");
        var list = array.map(function(str) {
           return  str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/gi, "\\$&");
        });
        console.log(list);

    };
```

Here is a quick sample the raw text file:

```
WinSoftware NetInstaller
NSISDL/1.2 (Mozilla)
Downloader Touch PFS 1.2.6
Downloader Touch PFS 1.2.7
Downloader ACP 1.0.2
Downloader MLR 1.0.0
Downloader Touch PFS 1.3.2
Downloader PFS 1.3.2
IEDLL
```

If I do something like this in console and pass it a string it escapes it correctly:

```
var escapeRegExp = function escapeRegExp(str) {
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/gi, "\\$&");
};
```

I get this as output, which is what I expect:

```
  ['downloader touch pfs 1\.3\.1',
  'downloader pfs 1\.3\.1',
  'downloader touch pfs 1\.2\.6',
  'awi v5\.12\.843']
```

Can anyone explain what is happening and why I'm getting the duplicated escape?

Comment: maybe they just look off in the console as an array, try looking at a JSON.stringify version...

Comment: One thing, you have far too many escape characters in your character class.  You can get away with `str.replace(/[-[{}()*+?.^$\]\/\\|]/gi, "\\$&");` - I moved all the characters that require escaping to the end of the class.  I dont think this is the issue, but it doesnt hurt to change. Note - the hyphen doesnt need escaping if it is the first or last character in the class, otherwise it definitely needs to be escaped.

Comment: the escape char appears twice even if stringified

Comment: does they appear even if you stringify the whole array and fs.writeFile that string? you might also try wrapping a paren around the class in the regexp and replacing with "\\$1" instead of "\\$&" ...

Comment: Shoot! @dandavis, you were right. It is the console escaping it. I feel really dumb, but thanks! I wasted a like an hour looking at this. I finally set webstorm in debug and stepped through a small set of the data. I noticed the array values were set properly when i exited the function.  I used array.toString() as saw the proper value.